# Migrating adapter mapping to latest ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `CouchDB` based backend. As in every document-based store, deeply nested properties are first-class citizens. That means, a nested property does not *necessarily* refer to an independent object. Often, a nested property is just used to structure complex objects, without implying any `belongsTo` or `hasMany` relationship. One direct consequence of this is that nested "objects" (which are not really objects) have no IDs.

Since ember-data does not directly supported nested properties, until now I have been modelling these objects using `belongsTo` relationships, with success. This is the data structure that I am receiving from my backend:

```
{
    "agents": [
        {
            "_id": "04ef35dd-6ab9-492f-ada6-0d4f4de9610a",
            "genproperties": {
                "playable-url": null
            },
            "org_id": 11653,
            "outputs": {
                "exten": null,
                "extension": "c4facb9d-850c-4b67-9592-b467129fa9d4",
                "jumpIfBusy": null,
                "jumpIfNoAnswer": null,
                "nextnode": "a1e00fb9-8604-4119-8515-3a31a36c60d1",
                "startnode": null
            },
            "properties": {
                "agent_status": "online",
                "allowed_portlets": [
                    "xxx-portlet",
                    "yyy-portlet",
                    "zzz-portlet",
                    "uuu-portlet",
                    "ppp-portlet"
                ],
                "default_portlet": "xxx-portlet",
                "email": "a.b@c.com",
                "enabled_portlets": [
                    "xxx-portlet",
                    "yyy-portlet",
                    "zzz-portlet",
                    "uuu-portlet",
                ],
                "first_name": "John",
                "main-service": null,
                "name": "John Ferdinand Smith",
                "portlet_language": "en",
                "pov-org": null,
                "services": {
                    "associated": {}
                },
                "surname1": "Ferdinand",
                "surname2": "Smith"
            },
            "type": "wav-user"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false,
    namespace: App.config.API_NAMESPACE,
    url: mynamespace.apiUrl,
    serializer: App.MetaRESTSerializer.create(),
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var ajaxPromise = this._super(url, type, hash);
        if (App.config.DEBUG_ADAPTER) { console.log('>>>>> REQUESTED > %s:%s > hash=%o ajaxPromise=%o', type, url, hash, ajaxPromise); }
        ajaxPromise.then(function(json){
            if (App.config.DEBUG_ADAPTER) { console.log('>>>>> RECEIVED > %s:%s > %o', type, url, json); }
        });
        return ajaxPromise;
    }
});
```

These are my current model definitions:

```
App.NodeOutputs = DS.Model.extend({
    startnode      : DS.attr('string'),
    jumpIfBusy     : DS.attr('string'),
    jumpIfNoAnswer : DS.attr('string'),
    nextnode       : DS.attr('string'),
    extension      : DS.attr('string'),
    exten          : DS.attr('string'),
});

App.NodeMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    nodeType    : DS.attr('string'),
    nodeSubtype : DS.attr('string'),
    outputs     : DS.belongsTo('App.NodeOutputs'),
});

App.Adapter.map('App.GenProperties', {
    playableUrl : {key: 'playable-url'},
});

App.AgentProperties = App.CommonProperties.extend({
    default_portlet  : DS.attr('string'),
    allowed_portlets : DS.attr('rawTransform'),
    portlet_language : DS.attr('string'),
    verified_emails  : DS.attr('rawTransform'),
    email            : DS.attr('string'),
    agent_status     : DS.attr('string'),
});

App.Agent = DS.Model.extend(App.NodeMixin, {
    properties    : DS.belongsTo('App.AgentProperties'),
    genproperties : DS.belongsTo('App.GenProperties'),
});
```

And these are my mappings:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.NodeOutputs', {
    startnode      : {key: 'startnode'},
    jumpIfBusy     : {key: 'jumpIfBusy'},
    jumpIfNoAnswer : {key: 'jumpIfNoAnswer'},
    nextnode       : {key: 'nextnode'},
    extension      : {key: 'extension'},
    exten          : {key: 'exten'},
});

App.Adapter.map('App.Agent', {
    nodeType       : { key: 'type' },
    nodeSubtype    : { key: 'subtype' },
    outputs        : { embedded: 'always' },
    properties     : { embedded: 'always' }
    genproperties  : { embedded: 'always' }
});
```

That was working perfectly with `ember-data#0.0.14`. Now I am moving to `ember-data#1.0.0-beta.3`, and it seems the `DS.RESTAdapter.map` is no longer supported.

I have taken a look at these resources:

- the [migration guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration)
- and the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_across-the-board-normalization) (hidden on the methods tab)
- also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18689566/647991)

But I still have no idea how to accomplish these two simple tasks:

- how to define simple key mappings, like `type` -> `nodeType` (json -> ember model)
- how to specify that a `belongsTo` is `embedded: 'always'`

**Question** : Is there some sample code showcasing key mappings and embedded properties for the latest ember-data? Does it support embedded properties **without** IDs?

I have over 30 mappings to migrate, so I'd better make sure to understand what I am doing before starting with it.